# Twitter Bot - node.js - unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, twitter, bots

```
I'm decently new to javascript, and decided to create a twitterbot using node.js
```

First I got an authentication error, I added .js to the end of the file name and i got no error messages that I could see, added the functions and the search and am now getting

SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

```
at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
```

my code is the following:

```
//require files

var Twit = require('twit');
var config = require('./config.js');
console.log ("THE BOT HAS STARTED!");
var T = new Twit(config);


//retweet function

var retweet = function() {
  var params = {
    q: '#perfect, #awesome' ,
    result_type: 'recent'
  }
}

Twitter.get('search/tweets', params, function(err, data) {
  // if there no errors grab id of tweet
    if (!err) {
        var retweetId = data.statuses[0].id_str;
        // Tell TWITTER to retweet
        Twitter.post('statuses/retweet/:id', {
            id: retweetId
        }, function(err, response) {
            if (response) {
                console.log('Retweeted!!!');
            }
            if (err) {
                console.log('Something went wrong while RETWEETING... 
Duplication maybe...');
        }
        });
    }
    // if unable to Search a tweet
    else {
      console.log('Something went wrong while SEARCHING...');
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need API Key, API Secret, Access Token und Access Token Secret. You will find undder “Keys and Access Token”. The Access Token you have to create by clicking on “Generate Access Token”.

Comment: I did that and linked it in a seperate file (config.js)